# WinDbg: How to get WinDbg's Locals/Watch to support complex VB6 types (collection, custom classes)?

Tags: vb6, windbg

First, is this even possible?  And if so how would I do this?  I'm particularly interested in the Collection class and custom VB classes.

Particularly welcome would be a book/reference on this subject:  I have "Advanced Windows Debugging", but I need more help when analyzing a dump file involving a VB6 component.

Once I have to start inspecting the state of VB objects, I'm in over my head!

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with the debugger built into the VB 6 IDE?

Comment: @Cody Probably that it can't analyse dump files, as requested in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there's nothing specifically out there about debugging and visualizing VB6 objects from WinDBG.

Matthew Curland's book, "Advanced VB Power techniques for everyday programmers"

```
 http://www.powervb.com/
```

Is probably the best book out there that kind of gets close.

He does work through the memory layouts of VB6 classes and the stack, which would definitely help (it helped me a TON when I was reverse engineering the return addresses off the stack).

That said, things like the Collection object are pretty complex internally, so how much it helps would be debatable. Simpler "name value pair" type objects should be relatively straightforward to resolve from WinDBG, though.

Comment: The book does look very promising, but it looks like they don't bundle the CD anymore.  I'm waiting on a response from Matthew Curland, to see if his CD installation is still available.

Comment: I believe the way it works is that the book has a URL in it, you go there, and it asks for a specific word from a specific page in the book (to prove you have it) and then you can download all the latest code.

Comment: A bit late, but confirmed; for anyone reading this thread and looking for similar help.